# Query/Update MS Access Records

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I am attempting to populate items into a datagrid and then update them back into the database using 2 buttons (one loads, one will save) and a datagrid on a form.  I keep running into "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression" upon update and I am not sure why.  Another question i have is where do my DataAdapter and Dataset need to be dimensioned in memory? Under the class?

```
    'this loads my data from db into datagrid

    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim sql As String

    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=dbsrc.mdb"

    con.Open()
    sql = "SELECT * from [Employee Assignments]"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "Assignments")

    con.Close()

    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Assignments")
```

The following code should update my database to reflect changes made in the datagridview

```
    'this will eventually update the datagrid back into the db

    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

    'Dim sql As String
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=dbsrc.mdb"

    con.Open()

    da.Update(ds, "Assignments")

    con.Close()

    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Assignments")
```

I read this artcle on msdn - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx - but it did not seem to help much, I am confused but I believe my problem is not identifying and passing the correct dataset back into the database.  How should I deal with the dataset that I pull, modify, and then send back into the DB using the DataAdapter?

Comment: Could you try to change the name of the table to remove the space inside and check if then it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a table contains spaces in its name you should inform the CommandBuilder about this problem 
setting the [QuotePrefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommandbuilder.quoteprefix.aspx) and QuoteSuffix property to avoid errors

```
cb.QuotePrefix = "["
cb.QuoteSuffix = "]"
```

The default for these twos is an empty string and thus, when you try to write your changes back to the database, you get a syntax error.

Comment: but do you think that could be issue? His data is loaded i guess correctly in datagrid

Comment: If you notice the select query has the square brackets. It is the update query automatically generated by the CommandBuilder that gets confused.

Comment: yes i noticed it but was not sure if this could be issue when updating

Comment: yeah the data loaded correctly into the grid, his solution was correct.  Such a small thing to overlook, thanks!